# Unattended upgrades vs cronjob including apt update && apt full-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, software-updates

Is it useful or necessary to run `unattended upgrades` if you already have a daily root cron that runs `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y`?

Comment: Please edit your question so that the commands are in markdown (put them between backquotes). Also, your commands won't always work. `apt` will almost always ask you to confirm your action. You will want to do `apt-get -y full-upgrade` if you want to do it automatically in cron.

Comment: The command in your edit will also not work (feel free to check it). Use the one i mentioned.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you'll have to remove `sudo`. Cron will make sure root-permissions are available

Comment: The crontab commands work. And oddly actually doesn't work without sudo. But that's not the point of my question.

Comment: You can indeed remove your cron-entries with a correctly configured `unattended-upgrades` package

Comment: If you would decide to keep the cron-method then find out how and where exactly you placed it in cron. (Users can also create a personal crontab and the 6th entry on the system-wide crontab might have been changed to another user)

Comment: I forget to mention something important: If your system is a desktop then it's fun to let it automatically upgrade. Things might break but it's only a desktop after all. Just make sure you never do this on a server. There it it is almost always a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tangible gain to running `unattended-upgrades` if you already have those commands run regularly, no.